# GPX parsing. Calculate Speed. Python

Tags: python, xml, gps, gpx

I am trying to analyze the speed of every point GPS gathered data. I am using gpxpy and I have gotten to print out a few things such as max speed, start and end time, moving time, etc from a gpx file, but I do not know how to print the speed,lat,long, etc for every point. The gpx file I have has 462 points and I would like to know more about each point. The code I have is below:

```
def print_gpx_part_info(gpx_part, indentation='    '):
"""
gpx_part may be a track or segment.
"""
length_2d = gpx_part.length_2d()
length_3d = gpx_part.length_3d()

moving_time, stopped_time, moving_distance, stopped_distance, max_speed = gpx_part.get_moving_data()
print('%sTotal Moving time: (hr/min/sec) %s' % (indentation, format_time(moving_time)))
#print('%sStopped distance: %sm' % stopped_distance)
#print('%sMax speed: %sm/s = %skph' % (indentation, max_speed, max_speed * 60. ** 2 / 1000. if max_speed else 0))
print('%sMax speed: %smph' % (indentation,  max_speed * 2.3694 if max_speed else 0))

start_time, end_time = gpx_part.get_time_bounds()
print('%sStarted: %s' % (indentation, start_time))
print('%sEnded: %s' % (indentation, end_time))

points_no = len(list(gpx_part.walk(only_points=True)))
print('%sPoints: %s' % (indentation, points_no))

print('')

def print_gpx_info(gpx):
print('File: %s' % gpx_file)

if gpx.name: 
    print('  GPX name: %s' % gpx.name)
if gpx.description:
    print('  GPX description: %s' % gpx.description)

print_gpx_part_info(gpx)

for track_no, track in enumerate(gpx.tracks):
    for segment_no, segment in enumerate(track.segments):
        print '    Track #%s, Segment #%s' % (track_no, segment_no)
        print_gpx_part_info(segment, indentation='        ')
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The GPXTrackPoint class has a method speed_between(another_gpx_track_point). Just iterate through all points and call this function for neighboring points.

The GPX file format also allows for the speed to be saved in the GPX point directly. If that's the case for your track, you don't need to calculate with speed_between()... Just use gpx_track_point.speed attribute.

I'm writing this from head (ignore typoos:), but this is more-or-less the code:

```
for track in gpx.tracks:
  for segment in track.segments:
    for point_no, point in enumerate(segment.points):
      if point.speed != None:
        print "Speed=", point.speed
      elif point_no > 0:
        printf "Calculated speed=", point.speed_between(segment.points[point_no - 1])
```

BTW, you can calculate the speeds between the current point and the previous one *and* the current point and the next one and then average those values to have a better speed.

Answer (score 0):

All speeds can be calculated using:

```
segment = gpx.tracks[0].segments[0]
for ind, point in enumerate(segment.points):
    point.speed = segment.get_speed(ind)
```

This gives the same result as averaging between the speeds between the current point and the previous one and the current point and the next one using

```
point.speed_between(point_ind)
```

which puzz suggested.